# Create container image using env variables

Tags: kubernetes

I am creating some cron jobs in kubernetes that are to run after three months. While the image name of the container that starts these cron jobs is well known, the version that is to be run is somewhat futuristic.

The version of the image cannot be known when I schedule the `cronjob`, as I want the cronjob to run the latest production deployment that is available at that time. There is no `latest tag` in our `production deployment`, the version has to be picked up from a config map.

- Is there a way to specify the container image in the cronjob, so that the image version is resolved using the env variable specified from a config map?

Comment: Its equally easy to update a cronjob-manifest as it is to update a configmap.

Comment: these are updated from code, not manual updates. some of the k8 objects are helm created while some of them are created by application code, adding to the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to specify the container image in the cronjob, so that the image version is resolved using the env variable specified from a config map?

You can try `gitRepo` Volume to achieve this.

Instead of writing here, you can refer [gitRepo volume in category](http://kuberneteshttps://livebook.manning.com/concept/kubernetes/gitrepo-volume)

**Note:** In the current version of Kubernetes it has been deprecated.

However, the same can be configured in [initContainer config](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#gitrepo). Ref for the [snipped](https://blog.frankel.ch/versatility-kubernetes-initcontainer/).

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: config-volume               
    emptyDir: {}
  initContainers:
  - name: clone
    image: alpine/git:1.0.4           
    volumeMounts:
    - name: config-volume
      mountPath: /config              
    envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: cfg                   
    command: ['/bin/sh', '-c']        
    args: ['git clone --branch $(version) https://github.com/ajavageek/foo-config && mv foo-config/* /config']
  containers:
  - name: foo
    image: ajavageek/foo:1.0          
    volumeMounts:
    - name: config-volume
      mountPath: /config              
      readOnly: true
```